# Is it possible to write in a two-columns style in restructuredtext?

Tags: restructuredtext

I would like to write a research paper using restructuredtext, is it possible to have the two-column style inherent to this kind of document? I looked at the [specifications](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html) but apart using a table which will be a real pain I haven't been able to find an alternative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can output 2-column in any of the formats docutils outputs.

If what you want is a 2-column **ReST source** then it's much harder.

Since there are no pages, it may not even make sense (imagine if the columns are 5000 lines long ;-), so I will assume you mean in the output, be it HTML, PDF or whatever.

For PDF, using rst2pdf, it's trivial, you only need to use the *-s twocolumn* option.

For HTML, it's a CSS thing, and I am sure google can help you.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Of course I didn't want to split my rest source this makes no sense to me ^^

I finally wrote my paper using latex, but next time thanks to you I'll give ReST a try :)

Comment: Another options might have been to try https://NoTex.ch: It has build in support for two column PDFs, but instead of *rst2pdf* it uses *Sphinx* (in combination with the LaTex `\twocolumn` command).

Answer (score 5):

If you wan't two column latex from reST you can get it with:

```
rst2latex --documentoptions=twocolumn source.rst
```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible with rst2pdf but your layout has to be kept within `PageBreak`. In otherwords you cannot have 1 column layout and 2 column layout on one page.

```
.. raw:: pdf 

      PageBreak twoColumn 

some text in two columns 


.. raw:: pdf 

      PageBreak oneColumn 

some text in one column
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found a way to do so with ReST. You really should consider [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) for your research paper, especially for citations ([BibTex](http://www.bibtex.org/)), if you want to write it in plain text. You can easily switch between one and two columns:

```
% remove "twocolumn" for a single column
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
Text here...
\end{document}
```

See [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) for a good reference.

Comment: yes... seems there is no way in ReST, the only paper styles that I found using ReST were single columned. Guess I'll have to learn Latex ;)

Comment: Good luck! LaTeX is aggravating at times, but it's still better than Word. Also, be sure to use a Makefile (or Rakefile if you're into that) for your paper - it'll make compiling a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

using sphinx

```sh
$ python3 -m venv ~/venv ; . ~/venv/bin/activate                                                          
$ pip install sphinx
$ sphinx-quickstart    # answer default to all questions                               
$ tree                                                
.                                                                                                   
├── _build                                                                                          
├── conf.py                                                                                         
├── index.rst                                                                                       
├── Makefile                                                                                        
├── rapport.rst                                                                                     
├── README.rst                                                                                      
├── requirements.txt                                                                                
├── _static
```

To have laxtex A4, article with control on margins and 2 columns: add this to `conf.py`:

```py
    # -- Options for LaTeX output --------------------------------                                    
    latex_elements = {                                                                                
      'papersize': 'a4paper',  # 'letterpaper' or 'a4paper'                                           
      'pointsize': '10pt',     # font size (default is 10pt)                                          
      'sphinxsetup': 'hmargin={1.5cm,1.5cm}, vmargin={2cm,2cm}',                                      
      'classoptions': ',twocolumn',    # to have two columns                                          
      }                                                                                               
    latex_theme = 'howto'  # 'manual' to make a book, 'howto' to make an article                      
    latex_logo = 'src/images/spqr_300px.png'
```

Crate some `rst` files::

```sh
    $ mkdir -p src                                                                                    
    $ touch src/antiquite.rst src/biographie.rst src/moderne.rst
```

Then we need to define the main TOC table of content in the main `index.rst` file,     this TOC file will refer to rst files to include in the document::

```
    $ cat index.rst                                                                                   
    Exposé                                                                                    
    ===============                                                                                   
                                                                                                      
    .. toctree::                                                                                      
       :maxdepth: 3                                                                                   
       :caption: Table des Matieres:                                                                  
                                                                                                      
       /src/antiquite.rst                                                                             
       /src/biographie.rst                                                                            
       /src/moderne.rst                                                                               
    $
```

From the folder where `Makefile` is,  call::

- `$ make html` to create html and point Firefox to `_build/html/index.html`
- `$ make pdflatex` to create pdf and point evince to `_build/latex/*.pdf`

#### you got a two column article in pdflatex !